# exiftool does not list GPS location from an iPhone

Tags: exiftool, gps

In Photos, Get Info displays a small map with photo location, so gps data was acquired and recordered. But it is not listed in exiftool output. How can I get latitude/longitude for scripting?

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.78
File Name                       : IMG_0016.jpg
Directory                       : /Users/danielstonek27/Desktop/fotos de Photos
File Size                       : 909 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:10:05 13:23:17-03:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2015:10:05 13:23:25-03:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2015:10:05 13:23:17-03:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Make                            : Apple
Camera Model Name               : iPad mini 2
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : Photos 1.0.1
Modify Date                     : 2015:10:05 14:22:23
Exposure Time                   : 1/30
F Number                        : 2.4
Exposure Program                : Program AE
ISO                             : 32
Exif Version                    : 0221
Date/Time Original              : 2015:10:05 14:22:23
Create Date                     : 2015:10:05 14:22:23
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/30
Aperture Value                  : 2.4
Brightness Value                : 4.801206732
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Metering Mode                   : Multi-segment
Flash                           : No flash function
Focal Length                    : 3.3 mm
Subject Area                    : 1295 967 1425 851
Run Time Flags                  : Valid
Run Time Value                  : 422649301168458
Run Time Epoch                  : 0
Run Time Scale                  : 1000000000
Sub Sec Time Original           : 808
Sub Sec Time Digitized          : 808
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : sRGB
Exif Image Width                : 1936
Exif Image Height               : 2592
Sensing Method                  : One-chip color area
Scene Type                      : Directly photographed
Exposure Mode                   : Auto
White Balance                   : Auto
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 32 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Lens Info                       : 3.3mm f/2.4
Lens Make                       : Apple
Lens Model                      : iPad mini 2 back camera 3.3mm f/2.4
XMP Toolkit                     : XMP Core 5.4.0
Creator Tool                    : Photos 1.0.1
Date Created                    : 2015:10:05 14:22:23
Current IPTC Digest             : d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
IPTC Digest                     : d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
Profile CMM Type                : Lino
Profile Version                 : 2.1.0
Profile Class                   : Display Device Profile
Color Space Data                : RGB
Profile Connection Space        : XYZ
Profile Date Time               : 1998:02:09 06:49:00
Profile File Signature          : acsp
Primary Platform                : Microsoft Corporation
CMM Flags                       : Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer             : IEC
Device Model                    : sRGB
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent                : Perceptual
Connection Space Illuminant     : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator                 : HP
Profile ID                      : 0
Profile Copyright               : Copyright (c) 1998 Hewlett-Packard Company
Profile Description             : sRGB IEC61966-2.1
Media White Point               : 0.95045 1 1.08905
Media Black Point               : 0 0 0
Red Matrix Column               : 0.43607 0.22249 0.01392
Green Matrix Column             : 0.38515 0.71687 0.09708
Blue Matrix Column              : 0.14307 0.06061 0.7141
Device Mfg Desc                 : IEC http://www.iec.ch
Device Model Desc               : IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGB
Viewing Cond Desc               : Reference Viewing Condition in IEC61966-2.1
Viewing Cond Illuminant         : 19.6445 20.3718 16.8089
Viewing Cond Surround           : 3.92889 4.07439 3.36179
Viewing Cond Illuminant Type    : D50
Luminance                       : 76.03647 80 87.12462
Measurement Observer            : CIE 1931
Measurement Backing             : 0 0 0
Measurement Geometry            : Unknown
Measurement Flare               : 0.999%
Measurement Illuminant          : D65
Technology                      : Cathode Ray Tube Display
Red Tone Reproduction Curve     : (Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Green Tone Reproduction Curve   : (Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Blue Tone Reproduction Curve    : (Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Image Width                     : 1936
Image Height                    : 2592
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Aperture                        : 2.4
Image Size                      : 1936x2592
Run Time Since Power Up         : 4 days 21:24:09
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 9.7
Shutter Speed                   : 1/30
Create Date                     : 2015:10:05 14:22:23.808
Date/Time Original              : 2015:10:05 14:22:23.808
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.003 mm
Field Of View                   : 58.7 deg
Focal Length                    : 3.3 mm (35 mm equivalent: 32.0 mm)
Hyperfocal Distance             : 1.46 m
Light Value                     : 9.1
```

After installing El Capitan and the lastest exiftool version

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.02
File Name                       : IMG_4839.jpg
Directory                       : /Users/danielstonek27/Desktop/fotos de Photos
File Size                       : 1847 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:10:05 12:59:07-03:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2015:10:06 19:59:17-03:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2015:10:05 12:59:07-03:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Make                            : Apple
Camera Model Name               : iPhone 5s
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : Photos 1.0.1
Modify Date                     : 2015:10:05 12:54:19
Exposure Time                   : 1/1109
F Number                        : 2.2
Exposure Program                : Program AE
ISO                             : 32
Exif Version                    : 0221
Date/Time Original              : 2015:10:05 12:54:19
Create Date                     : 2015:10:05 12:54:19
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/1109
Aperture Value                  : 2.2
Brightness Value                : 12.05130785
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Metering Mode                   : Multi-segment
Flash                           : Auto, Did not fire
Focal Length                    : 4.2 mm
Subject Area                    : 1631 1223 1795 1077
Run Time Flags                  : Valid
Run Time Value                  : 54353155612041
Run Time Epoch                  : 0
Run Time Scale                  : 1000000000
Sub Sec Time Original           : 417
Sub Sec Time Digitized          : 417
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : sRGB
Exif Image Width                : 3264
Exif Image Height               : 2448
Sensing Method                  : One-chip color area
Scene Type                      : Directly photographed
Exposure Mode                   : Auto
White Balance                   : Auto
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 29 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Lens Info                       : 4.15mm f/2.2
Lens Make                       : Apple
Lens Model                      : iPhone 5s back camera 4.15mm f/2.2
XMP Toolkit                     : XMP Core 5.4.0
Creator Tool                    : Photos 1.0.1
Date Created                    : 2015:10:05 12:54:19
Current IPTC Digest             : d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
IPTC Digest                     : d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
Profile CMM Type                : Lino
Profile Version                 : 2.1.0
Profile Class                   : Display Device Profile
Color Space Data                : RGB
Profile Connection Space        : XYZ
Profile Date Time               : 1998:02:09 06:49:00
Profile File Signature          : acsp
Primary Platform                : Microsoft Corporation
CMM Flags                       : Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer             : IEC
Device Model                    : sRGB
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent                : Perceptual
Connection Space Illuminant     : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator                 : HP
Profile ID                      : 0
Profile Copyright               : Copyright (c) 1998 Hewlett-Packard Company
Profile Description             : sRGB IEC61966-2.1
Media White Point               : 0.95045 1 1.08905
Media Black Point               : 0 0 0
Red Matrix Column               : 0.43607 0.22249 0.01392
Green Matrix Column             : 0.38515 0.71687 0.09708
Blue Matrix Column              : 0.14307 0.06061 0.7141
Device Mfg Desc                 : IEC http://www.iec.ch
Device Model Desc               : IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGB
Viewing Cond Desc               : Reference Viewing Condition in IEC61966-2.1
Viewing Cond Illuminant         : 19.6445 20.3718 16.8089
Viewing Cond Surround           : 3.92889 4.07439 3.36179
Viewing Cond Illuminant Type    : D50
Luminance                       : 76.03647 80 87.12462
Measurement Observer            : CIE 1931
Measurement Backing             : 0 0 0
Measurement Geometry            : Unknown
Measurement Flare               : 0.999%
Measurement Illuminant          : D65
Technology                      : Cathode Ray Tube Display
Red Tone Reproduction Curve     : (Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Green Tone Reproduction Curve   : (Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Blue Tone Reproduction Curve    : (Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Image Width                     : 3264
Image Height                    : 2448
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Aperture                        : 2.2
Image Size                      : 3264x2448
Megapixels                      : 8.0
Run Time Since Power Up         : 15:05:53
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 7.0
Shutter Speed                   : 1/1109
Create Date                     : 2015:10:05 12:54:19.417
Date/Time Original              : 2015:10:05 12:54:19.417
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.004 mm
Field Of View                   : 63.7 deg
Focal Length                    : 4.2 mm (35 mm equivalent: 29.0 mm)
Hyperfocal Distance             : 1.82 m
Light Value                     : 14.0
```

And to check GPS data exists
[image]

Comment: What version of ExifTool do you have? How are you running it?

Comment: I've just upgraded to the last version. I edited the question.

Comment: Are you checking the original image, or something that you've exported? if you've exported (it appears that you have based on the file location in your screenshots) note that you need to *check* the "Location Information" box on the Export dialog of Photos.

Comment: Photos is an awful tool. You are not able to do anything with its images like drag an drop them to Photoshop or email icons.
I have to (and it seems nothing has changed in this new version) copy images I want to do something with them, to a special folder (drag and drop) so then I can manage them. From this folder I got that exiftool data. Photos->File->Export Original File does keep location data, same as what you say Export 1 photo and Include Location.  Thanks

Comment: @DanWolfgang Post that as an answer

Comment: Photos setting also has an unchecked checkbox Metadata: Include location information for published items. Checking it those drag and drop images to a folder will containg GPS data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you checking the original image, or something that you've exported? if you've exported (it appears that you have based on the file location in your screenshots) note that you need to check the "Location Information" box on the Export dialog of Photos.

Once exported with location metadata, `exiftool --groupname [file]` will show you just what you expect to see.

Comment: Photos setting also has an unchecked checkbox Metadata: Include location information for published items. Checking it those drag and drop images to a folder will containg GPS data

Answer (score 0):

iPhone GPS data is shown by Exiftool.  It is in the first Exif section.

```
Lens Make                       : Apple
Lens Model                      : iPhone 5s back camera 4.15mm f/2.2
GPS Latitude Ref                : North
GPS Latitude                    : 33.055130°
GPS Longitude Ref               : West
GPS Longitude                   : 96.673133°
GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
GPS Altitude                    : 164.3202247 m
GPS Time Stamp                  : 20:34:13.42
GPS Speed Ref                   : km/h
GPS Speed                       : 0
GPS Img Direction Ref           : True North
GPS Img Direction               : 43.81863561
GPS Dest Bearing Ref            : True North
GPS Dest Bearing                : 223.8186528
GPS Date Stamp                  : 0000:00:00
```

Comment: Mine did not display any GPS data. Lots of info but location.
It was using Yosemite. Now I've upgraded to El Capitan and $ exiftool 'command not found'. I will install it again and let's see.

Comment: Despite the upgrade Terminal keeps outputs history. I edited my question.

Comment: You might check a new unedited JPG straight out of the camera. Many photo editors will omit some sections of the Exif data when they save a file.